# In python how do I access an instance of a class from a parent or top-level module from withing a submodule

Tags: python, inheritance, module, instance

I'm a python newbie, and developing my first python app using the CherryPy Web Server and Jinja 2 Templating engine.

I'm using a Velleman K8055 USB experiment board, which has a python module that I'm importing.

For the K8055 to function properly I have to create an instance of the class within the K8055 module, then open a connection to the board... As far as I understand it I have to keep that connection/instance running, and use that sole instance to control the board, even from within sub-modules.

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to access the previously initialised instance of the K8055 from within my sub-modules/packages...

I have a Application structure very similar to the following...

```
SmartyPi/
SmartyPi/smartypi.py
SmartyPi/smartypi/__init__.py
SmartyPi/smartypi/scheduler/
SmartyPi/smartypi/scheduler/__init__.py
SmartyPi/smartypi/scheduler/Scheduler.py
SmartyPi/smartypi/web/
SmartyPi/smartypi/web/__init__.py
SmartyPi/smartypi/web/k8055.py
SmartyPi/smartypi/web/root.py
SmartyPi/smartypi/web/schedule.py
```

In 'SmartyPi/smartypi.py' I have initialised my instance of the k8055 object with:

```
from pyk8055 import k8055
k = k8055(0)
```

I'd like to be able to access the same instance of 'k' from places like:

```
SmartyPi/smartypi/web/k8055.py
SmartyPi/smartypi/web/schedule.py
```

I can't seem to figure it out on my own...

Was 'SmartyPi/smartypi.py' not the best place to create my K8055 instance?

Should I be making it somewhere else, and how can I make this work as I need it to?

Comment: Why not create your `k8055` instance in `smartypi.py` and then have `k8055.py` and `schedule.py` contain functions that except a `k8055` instance as a parameter, so you can pass `k` to those functions?

Comment: Passing the 'k' instance around as a parameter is a little tricky as 'k8055.py' and 'schedule.py' are called from within CherryPy when a request for 'http://localhost/k8055' or 'http://localhost/schedule' is made by the user. Is there a way that I can just "IMPORT" a common module within my application that contains/makes those instances available to me?

Answer (score 0):

Add k = k8055(0) to the pyk8055 module (at the end). An than in all other modules just replace:

```
from pyk8055 import k8055
```

with

```
from pyk8055 import k
```

Note: I suggest to rename k with something more unique.

In case you cannot edit puk8055 module, create your own, call it i.e. globals.py:

```
from pyk8055 import k8055
k = k8055(0)
```

After that in other modules instead directly importing pyk8055, just import your module globals.py:

```
from globals import k
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've not got access to the source of the pyk8055 module So I've followed your second option of a "globals.py".

Unfortunately, although neater, this doesn't seem to attack my direct problem...

Whenever I run my function a second time, the originally intended "global" instance of my object is lost and replaced with a new instance which breaks the connection...

I have pastebin'd my "smartypi/web/k8055.py" source here -> http://pastebin.com/qSXHVTss -- any ideas??

Comment: "from smartypi.appglobals import globalK8055 as k" must be outside of function. This way k is added to module name space and is accessible to all functions within the module. At present appglobals are reimported every time you start your function, and deleted after functions complete.